# How to remove a class on modal leave

Tags: javascript, jquery

I implemented a JS code that allows me to have an image that follows my cursor when I'm in an area outside my modal.

Why not in CSS will you tell me? Because I needed to keep my cursor in addition to the image and not replace it.

Everything works wonderfully but the only undesirable effect is that the custom cursor does not remove itself if I do not move the mouse after leaving the modal because the function is based on a movemove and therefore it scans when the mouse moves ...

Does anyone know how to force the removeclass as soon as you leave the modal?

```js
const modalRoot = document.getElementById("modal-root");

window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
  if (event.target === modalRoot) {
    $(".cursor").addClass("cursor-visible");
    $(".cursor")[0].style.top = event.clientY + 15 + "px";
    $(".cursor")[0].style.left = event.clientX + 15 + "px";
  } else {
    $(".cursor").removeClass("cursor-visible");
  }
});
```

```html
<section id="modal-root">
  <div class="modal">
    <span class="quit_cross">x</span>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</section>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"leave the modal"* - obvious meaning would be "move the mouse out of the modal" - but that's covered.  Do you mean "when the modal closes without moving the mouse" (eg clicking the close button or pressing escape to close the dialog)?  If so, it depends on your modal - most framework modals have an event when the modal is closing, hook into that event and `$(".cursor").removeClass("cursor-visible");`

Comment: Secondly, most framework modals have an *overlay* shown to enhance the visibility of the modal (ie "grey-out" the background).  You could apply events / css to *that* element instead of checking for "not modal".  Setting up your css something like `.cursor { display:none; } .modal-background .cursor { display:block }` would mean it would only be shown when pointing at the background - keep your js to set the position (and keep your cursor+image as required)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. @freedomn-m
I don't think I'm using a framework, it's just a div that's displayed in the middle of the screen like this example : [link](https://codepen.io/vlrprbttst/pen/xOoxWo) I'm not very comfortable with javascript again sorry...

Comment: The demo above doesn't behave as you describe. Please revise so it does and we can see the problem.

Comment: If you're rolling-your-own modal, then you can easily add an event when you close the modal.

Comment: Or, if you're not making your modal reusable (which you should) and don't want to learn how to raise events, then add your code in the close modal directly, eg: https://jsfiddle.net/4axpLjv8/

Answer (score 0):

You could run a interval to check if the modal is still open.

```
var modalDisplayedInt;

window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
  if (event.target === modalRoot) {

    //CLEAR THE INTERVAL IF IT EXISTS
    clearInterval(modalDisplayedInt);

    //WAIT 1 SECOND THEN CHECK IF THE MODAL IS STILL DISPLAYED
    modalDisplayedInt = setInterval(function(){
        if(!$('.modal:visible').length){
            $(".cursor").removeClass("cursor-visible");
            clearInterval(modalDisplayedInt);
        }
    }, 1000);
    $(".cursor").addClass("cursor-visible");
    $(".cursor")[0].style.top = event.clientY + 15 + "px";
    $(".cursor")[0].style.left = event.clientX + 15 + "px";
  } else {
    $(".cursor").removeClass("cursor-visible");
  }
});
```